# my response.sendRedirect(); is not working

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, httpresponse

I'm trying to redirect a new page with this syntax

```
try {
        usuarios usu = new usuarios();
        usu.setNombreusuario(request.getParameter("parCodigo"));
        System.out.println(usu.getUsuario());
        usu.setContrasena(request.getParameter("parContrasenha"));
        System.out.println(usu.getContrasena());
        usu = usuariosDAO.login(usu);
        System.out.println("es valido? " + usu.isValid());
        if (usu.isValid()) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("usuario", usu.getUsuario());
            response.sendRedirect("/KolaEscocesaCRM/menumobile.jsp");
            return;
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/KolaEscocesaCRM/loginmobile.jsp");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My problem is that when I submit I get this:

> http://localhost:8084/KolaEscocesaCRM/srvMenu2?parCodigo=admin&parContrasenha=kola

I don't know what to do please any help would be fine

Comment: Please post the error, we cant click a link to your localhost ..

Comment: A redirect is always a get request so all parameters are encoded in the url as query parameters

Comment: thats my error that url is what i get after i redirect my page to menumobile.jsp i want to redirect to the link but sendRedirect is not working

Comment: Make sure that you did not write any output on response writer and provide complete patch in sendRedirect like http://localhost:8084//KolaEscocesaCRM/menumobile.jsp

Comment: Thank you for the help  now my code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you get a dear 404

Most of the time, because the entry application is mapped into something like `/myapp` instead of `/`(root)

The server says to the browser go to `/KolaEscocesaCRM/loginmobile.jsp` where it should be `/.myapp/KolaEscocesaCRM/loginmobile.jsp`

The simplest way is changing the context-path to root (`/` or empty string)